# Dynamically create queues and topics from the client with Qpid using AMQP 1.0

Tags: spring, jms, amqp, qpid

I'm trying to upgrade our old Qpid setup (AMQP 0-X based) to the latest proton version of Qpid based on AMQP 1.0 and running into an issue with dynamically creating durable or non-durable queues/topics from the client. We used to be able to do this utilizing Spring's `jms-generic:queue:someQueueName` (or topic in some of our cases) which would ultimately create the queue or topic for us after going through the dynamic destination resolver. However, this no longer seems to be the case as `createQueue/Topic` doesn't create the actual queue or topic anymore (at least what I've read on the JMS docs regarding `createQueue/Topic`).

So my concerns ultimately boil down to:

1) Is it still possible to dynamically create queues and topics using the newest Qpid JMS and Broker-J,

2) and if so, how can I using Qpid JMS and Broker-J to make it happen?

Thanks for your responses in advance.

Side note: I fully realize this is a pretty barebones, high-level overview, so I can provide more details as needed. I'm just hoping someone might be able to definitively answer (1) before I try moving on with (2).

Answer (score 0):

The new JMS client does not have a provision for automatically creating queues based on the address string; in part this is because AMQP 1.0 does not yet define a common mechanism for creating queues as such.

Qpid Broker-J does support the creation of queues/exchanges/etc. through a management protocol - but other brokers/services have not standardised on this yet.

The Broker system tests use AMQP management for dynamically creating entities... https://github.com/apache/qpid-broker-j/blob/master/systests/qpid-systests-jms-core/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/systests/AmqpManagementFacade.java

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Rob. My apologies for not responding sooner. I actually found this information the day I originally asked the question, but forgot to update with my findings. I was able to get Broker-J to create my queues and topics dynamically after making minor changes to my queue and topic uris based on some clues in the Broker-J source code. Now I just need to figure out how tell the broker to make them durable!